# Strapi. Method Not Allowed custom question

Tags: post, strapi

Through postman, I'm trying to send a post request to create a post, but I get an error that is described in the question itself (error code - 405).

On top of all that, I've issued ALL permissions. What is the problem?

[image: my headers]

[image: my question]

grade collection -
[image: grade]

and schema.json from grade -

```
{
  "kind": "collectionType",
  "collectionName": "grades",
  "info": {
    "singularName": "grade",
    "pluralName": "grades",
    "displayName": "grade"
  },
  "options": {
    "draftAndPublish": true
  },
  "pluginOptions": {},
  "attributes": {
    "id_post": {
      "type": "biginteger"
    },
    "grade": {
      "type": "integer"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have some error in the query, like do you have field `id_post` that accepts integer?

Comment: You have to add contents of `src/api/grades/content-types/grades/schema.json` file to question

Comment: @antokhio i'm added code, check please

Comment: hi tested with same setup, https://gist.github.com/antokhio/7ade99d94e49668e1be1186ddea45e07 and i get no errors here, seems the problem is elsewhere, did you do `yarn strapi build` ?

Comment: no, it needs to be done in the root of the project?

Comment: the sampe place you do `yarn develop` or `npm run develop` and `npm run build` `yarn build` accordingly

Comment: daniil@daniil-laptop:~/hundred_plans$ npm run build yarn build

> hundred-plans@0.1.0 build
> strapi build yarn build

Building your admin UI with development configuration...

✔ Webpack
  Compiled successfully in 11.68s

Admin UI built successfully
daniil@daniil-laptop:~/hundred_plans$

Comment: this is my console - ```[2022-12-21 14:38:39.382] http: POST /api/grades/%0A%0A (4 ms) 40```

Comment: Hi, this `%0A%0A` looks like you have some extra characters after `/api/grades` witch is prolly the case, try to copy paste this url `http://localhost:1337/api/grades` and check there is no extra characters

Comment: Strange, I just wrote a new link and it all worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from comments, it seems the problem is two extra invisible characters after the url:

[image]

this line makes them visible:
`[2022-12-21 14:38:39.382] http: POST /api/grades/%0A%0A (4 ms) 40`

notice the `%0A%0A`

remove them or copy paste clean url:

```
http://localhost:1337/api/grades
```